# How to determine a cluster is not significant in online clustering?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, cluster-analysis

I'm clustering a data stream in real-time, more precisely Twitter stream. As data points (tweets) arrive from the stream, a point is assigned to the most similar cluster to it. During the clustering I'm tracking the sizes of all clusters over time. Whenever a cluster's size gets above the mean of all sizes, then I declare this cluster as significant or a trending cluster. However I'm unable to find a way to declare this cluster as non-trending or insignificant if its size stays static for a period of time. Because if it stays static that means people aren't issuing tweets about this topic, however its size will still be above the mean and hence it will remain a trending cluster even tho it's not.

One way I was thinking to solve this problem is by declaring a period parameter something like 10 minutes to see if its size stays the same then I declare it as non-increasing and so I remove it from the trending list.

I was wondering if there's a better approach to handle this problem than the period parameter or even how to decide the period parameter?

Comment: It seems the main theme of your question is related more to trend detection than to clustering. If that's the case, I'd suggest to repost with a different topic, and - as @Anony-Mousse says - you may also want to give some more color on what you're trying to model.

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on your application what an appropriate rule to forget old clusters is.

There is no general rule that we could share. Some people will want to keep the cluster around forever, others have elements age, and disband the cluster once it shrinks below a threshold size. And you apparently want to forget it once it doesn't grow anymore.

It's up to you, what you want to model.

Comment: what do you mean by "what I want to model". Modeling what exactly?